# "Listening up and down?"

Tags: idioms

Is "listening this music album up and down" correct English? It's supposed to mean "listening over and over again", but I've never seen it used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with others (and yourself) in that I have never heard this phrase in English.

To me, it sounds like a literal translation of the German "rauf- und runterhören", which is a popular (and somewhat informal) idiom in that language. (See Google search [one](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22rauf-+und+runterh%C3%B6ren%22), [two](http://www.google.com/search?q=rauf+und+runter+h%C3%B6ren).)

Comment: They aren't included in the Google Dictionary, what do they mean?

Comment: @Percy: "they" are just two different spellings of the same idiom, which, in German, means exactly what the OP says: "listen over and over again". It can be applied to a single song or an entire album. In the latter case, it has the connotation that you listen to the album without skipping any songs.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard or seen the phrase you mention.

I **have** heard / seen "listening up and down the dial" which refers to tuning in to radio stations at many different points along the broadcast frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard it either. Perhaps it's an analogy to the idiom of "looking (something) up and down"?

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression "look someone up and down" ([ref](http://esl.about.com/od/intermediatereading/a/Phrasal-Verbs-With-Look.htm)) which means to examine someone carefully. I think that it's this expressions that has been applied to listening to an album.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard that phrase before. Perhaps it is local slang? Some might consider it correct English if the word "to" was inserted between "listening" and "this".